# Can't get VScode to trimFinalNewlines

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just turned into a VScode developer from Atom. I have worked out all of the things needed to keep same, if not better workflow here but one thing bugs me alot. VScode will not remove empty lines at the end of the file.

My settings.json looks like this:

```
"files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
"files.insertFinalNewline": true,
"files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
"atomKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
"csscomb.formatOnSave": true............muchmore:)
```

Do I need to order the `"files.insertFinalNewline": true, "files.trimFinalNewlines": true` in another way? or is it something else I have done wrong?

Can't seem to find anyone else having this problem anymore since they introduced this to VScode..

Comment: I can not re-create this issue. I have put the settings in all orders possible (from autosave down to trimtrailing) and all settings seem to be working appropriately. Trimming all whitespace and empty new lines at the end of the file... What else can you say about your environment/workspace settings?

Comment: Since of last update it works for me, thanks anyways